# Jquery function not being executed

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to execute this function when a select list's (LevelId0) value change but its not being executed. Tried this inside `$(document).ready()` and outside of it. `hasFullAccess` is a local boolean variable in the window.

```
$("#LevelId0").change(function() {
    if (hasFullAccess) {
        alert("oy");
    }
    else {
        alert("oi");
        // var currentYear = (new Date).getFullYear();
        // $(".bound").val("01/01/" + (currentYear + 1));
        //$(".EffectiveDateClass").val("01/01/"+(currentYear +1));
    }
});​
```

***SOLUTION***

```
@if (!hasFullAccess)
    {
        <text>$(document).on('change', "#LevelId0, #CLevelId1", function() {
            var currentYear = (new Date).getFullYear();
            $("#LevelId1, #LevelId0").val($(this).val());
            $("#EffectiveDate0, #EffectiveDate1,.EffectiveDateClass").val("01/01/" + (currentYear + 1));
            });
        </text>
        }
```

Comment: Whatever else you do, keep it contained within a `document.ready` to ensure the element exists when your jQuery function is loaded.

Comment: Maybe post your HTML too.  There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your code, and change() works on select elements.

Comment: In addition to the document.ready advice, if your content updates dynamically you will want to delegate to a listener using `.on()`

Comment: The problem probably lies with your html code.  We need to see that if you want better help.

Comment: Please post your html.  I suspect .net is messing with your id.

Comment: Don't show you .NET code, show your HTML output.

Comment: @James Montagne - MVC 3 will not change any ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('change', "#LevelId0", function() {
        if (hasFullAccess) {
            alert("oy");
        } else {
            alert("oi"); // var currentYear = (new Date).getFullYear();    
            // $(".bound").val("01/01/" + (currentYear + 1));     
            //$(".EffectiveDateClass").val("01/01/"+(currentYear +1)); 
        }
    });
});
```

what you really want perhaps:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('change', "#LevelId0, #LevelId1", function() {
        updateValues();
    });
});
```

What does this alert in the `$(document).ready(`:

```
alert(hasFullAccess);
```

EDIT: ALTERED FUNCTION:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('change', "#LevelId0", function() {
        if (typeof hasFullAccess === "undefined") {
            alert("oy");
        } else {
            alert("oi");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I do not know what you mean by 'if statement', I see no if statement involved here except inside the triggered function.

Comment: Thats what I'm reffering to. Any code i put before the if statement gets executed but anything inside the the if or else is not being executed.

Comment: see my note at the end of my post, I suspect that. In case it is "undefined" you have your issue.

Comment: I achieved another way will post above